# using a 'RETURNING' clause in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there an easy way to do a 'RETURNING' clause in snowflake?

For example in postgres I can do something like

| COL 1 | COL 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xcvs |
| 2 | fdas |

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE(COL_2)
VALUES('ABCD')
RETURNING COL_1
```

Where COL_1 is set to be an auto incrementing ID, so for the above query I would expect the result '3' and the table to be like such

| COL 1 | COL 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xcvs |
| 2 | fdas |
| 3 | ABCD |

Comment: I have debated just using a second 'SELECT MAX(COL_1) FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE' but my fear here would be if running jobs in parallel and I could get some weird timing issues.

Comment: Can you accept gaps in the COL_1 sequence or does it need to be gap-free? Snowflake is an MPP so gap-free sequences have a performance penalty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake seems to lack `returning` or `last_insert_id`.

One option is to forego auto-incrementing primary keys and use a explicit [sequence](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html#).

```
create sequence example_table_seq1;

create table example_table (
  id number default example_table_seq1.nextval,
  col varchar(255)
);
```

Then, if need to know the ID, you can assign it to a variable and pass it in. This is [how Rails does it](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e722b74a924f4f2304c2c7c15d72c5824cf3c223/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L477).

```
set next_id = select example_table_seq1.nextval from dual;

insert into example_table (id, col)
values ($next_id, 'ABCD');
```

Or using a CTE.

```
with next_id as (
  select example_table_seq1.nextval as id from dual
)
insert into example_table (id, col)
select next_id.id, 'ABCD' from next_id;
```

And if you don't, let the default happen.

```
insert into example_table (col)
values ('ABCD');
```

The advantage of using a sequence, vs `select max(id)+1 from example_table`, is `nextval` will always return a new unique ID. Even if you're doing a lot of inserts at the same time, there's no danger of using a duplicate ID, and no need for locks nor transactions.

Comment: For the OP, if you insert a large number of rows (such as insert from a select or copying from a stage) Snowflake sequences guarantee uniqueness but do not guarantee gap-free sequences. This is because the optimizer will assign blocks of integers to each CPU core for the insert. If all that's required is uniqueness, a sequence is the way to go for performance. If you need a gap-free sequence, let us know.